# Automate calls on my behalf with Twilio

Tags: twilio

I'd like to have Twilio automate a voice call on my behalf until the end party picks up (normally, it's a busy signal). Once the end party successfully picks up, I'd like Twilio to automatically call my phone and connect me to that call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible with Twilio. You can use their [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) to initiate a call to the required number.

You would make a REST API call similar to the one below:

```
POST /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC30947.../Calls.json
From=YOUR_TELEPHONE_NUMBER&To=RECIPIENT_NUMBER&Url=http://www.myapp.com/myhandler.php& IfMachine=true
```

The parameter `IfMachine=true` will tell Twilio to pass to your specified URL the parameter: `AnsweredBy` which will either be:

- human
- machine

In your myhandler.php file you will then have TwiML (Twilio Markup Language) & some PHP:

**handler.php**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <?php
    if($_GET['AnsweredBy'] == 'human'){
    ?>
    <Say>Hi! We are going to connect you to... YOUR NAME</Say>
    <Dial>415-123-4567</Dial>
    <?php
    }else{
        // There was no answer - so we just hangup.
    ?>
    <Hangup/>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</Response>
```

Comment: In this particular case I'm expecting an answer from a machine, actually. I'm guessing I would simply omit the <Say> tag, right?

Comment: Yes. I just put the <Say> tag in just for an example. :)